# Is power rules used correctly here?

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

Question states:-

> if $y=\sqrt{\left(sinx\:+y\right)}$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}=$

The obvious thing to do here square then proceed. So,

$$y^2=sinx+y$$
Differentiating

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^2\right)=\frac{d}{dx}sinx\:+\frac{dy}{dx}$$

You can simply use the power rule which states (I just started this power rule today, so i hope I correctly stated it.)
$$\frac{d}{dx}\:f\left(x\right)^n=n\cdot f\left(x\right)^{n-1}.\frac{d}{dx}\:f\left(x\right)$$

But there is one problem that I encountered

Almost every site I looked up and my teacher including, simply substituted $f(x)=y$. How is that possible in this case? The best-case IMO would be representing y as a dependant variable on the only x, I am not sure how we do in this case.

Final answer

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\:=\frac{Cosx}{2y-1}$$

Comment: The dependency of $y$ on $x$ can be written $y=f(x)$. However, $y$ can be differentiated with respect to $x$ however it is written (assuming it is a differentiable function of $x$). The underlying function remains the same whatever notation you choose yo use for it. The notation $y'$ is often used for the derivative when it is obvious what you are differentiating by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Almost every site I looked up and my teacher including, simply substituted $f(x)=y$. How is that possible in this case? The best-case IMO would  be representing y as a dependant variable on the only x, I am not sure how we do in this case.

I am not sure what are you asking in this question but I think you are confused about $f(x)=y$. They substituted it becuase the function in the equation is $y(x)$(we just don't bother to write down the $x$ everytime).

In the formula the given function is $f(x)$ but in the equation it is $y$, so in order to use the formula, you have to substitute $f(x)=y$.

> Secondly even when they substituted, it went something like this
> $\frac{d}{dx}y^2=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$

If you just use the formula you have given which is-

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)^n=nf(x)^{n-1}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

Just substitute $f(x)=y$ (I hope that I correctly explained why we should do that)

Then $\frac{d}{dx}y^n=$ $ny^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$

Now take $n=2$

Then, $\frac{d}{dx}y^2=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$

> Shouldn't it be
> $\frac{d}{dx}y^2=2y\frac{dy^2}{dx}$

Well no it shouldn't,  because

$\frac{d}{dx}y^2$ and $\frac{dy^2}{dx}$ are the same thing.

And if you use the formula then the RHS doesn't have $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)^n$, it has $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$(note that the function is raised to the first power) but in your result

$\frac{d}{dx}y^2=2y\frac{dy^2}{dx}$ the function is raised to the second power.

## The result to the given question:-

$y=\sqrt{sin(x)+y}$

$y^2=sin(x)+y$

$\frac{dy^2}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}sin(x)+\frac{dy}{dx}$

$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=cos(x)+\frac{dy}{dx}$

$(2y-1)\frac{dy}{dx}=cos(x)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{cos(x)}{2y-1}$

You can solve it further by solving for $y$

$y^2-y-sin(x)=0$

$y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4sin(x)}}{2}$

So, $\frac{dy}{dx}$
$=\pm\frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt{1+4sin(x)}}$

Comment: thanks for elaborating on the second part, I figured out 2nd part was wrong and mentioned it too at the end but I guess I will edit it out

Comment: also @Ranjit, are you trying to tell in power rule, the functions does not need to be expressed as a function of x? like for example I can find $\frac{d}{dx}\left(y\right)$ in $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^4\right)$$ using power rule even if there may not be an implicit relation like $y=x^2$. I think its starting to make sense now

Comment: @Peter Phipps. I have mistaken in my calculation. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Adil Mohammed. If there is an implicit relation then you can use it. But in the question you have given, it is better not to write the implicit relation because it would make things complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to consider the implicif function$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{\sin (x)+y}-y=0$$
$$\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\cos (x)}{2 \sqrt{\sin (x)+y}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\sin (x)+y}}-1$$ and using the implicit function theorem
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} } {\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} }=\frac{\cos (x)}{2 \sqrt{\sin (x)+y}-1}=\frac{\cos (x)}{2 y-1}$$

Now, if you want to solve $f(x,y)=0$ for $y$, you have
$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(1\pm\sqrt{4 \sin (x)+1}\right)$$ which now makes
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\pm \frac{\cos (x)}{\sqrt{4 \sin (x)+1}}$$ which is *almost* your  answer.

Try to find why *almost* ?

Comment: +1 for telling about a new method and as for the last question, I need to think but I would say there has to be some relation between $\sqrt{4 \sin (x)}+1$ and $2y-1$

Comment: @AdilMohammed. It is not a new method (except you did not hear yet about the implicit function theorem). For sure, there is a relation but, as you saw, I exploited it only at the end.